# Is it possible to "lock" group of jobs across multiple gitlab pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have multiple jobs working with a single external resource (Server). The first job deploys the app to the environment, the second execute tests at this environment, third execute integration tests at this environment.

I know there is [Resource group](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/15536) option. But it locks only jobs. If two pipelines run concurrently I need to execute `job1`, `job2`, `job3` from the first pipeline, and only when the first pipeline release resource - the second pipeline can launch `jobs1-3`. Is there a way to achieve this? There are other jobs in the pipeline - they should work concurrently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be possible in 13.9 by using `resource_group` with process mode = `oldest_first`. Details available at: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/index.html#pipeline-level-concurrency-control-with-cross-projectparent-child-pipelines

Comment: Is there a way to set the process mode, in the SaaS version, without using a personal API token?

Comment: @davidA I don't think so

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be implemented through the `needs` and `resource_group` keywords and the gitlab API.

Every job receives the pipeline id to which it belongs as a `predefined-variable`. If you use the gitlab api, you can see the status of other jobs in the pipeline. If you can use this status, `needs` and `resource_group` keywords I think you can achieve what you intended. See the description of below code and its comments for more details.

```
stages:
  - ready
  - build

job1:
  stage: build
  needs: [starting_signal]
  script: 
    - sleep 10 && echo "job1"
job2:
  stage: build
  needs: [starting_signal]
  script:
    - sleep 20 && echo "job2"
job3:
  stage: build
  needs: [starting_signal]
  script:
    - sleep 30 && echo "job3"

starting_signal:
  stage: ready
  script:
    - # TODO: You need to implement it using the GitLab API.
    - # The starting condition for "job1-3" is
    - # that this `starting_signal` job finished successfully.
    - # And the condition that ends with the success of this job
    - # is that `traffic_light` becomes running.

traffic_light: 
  stage: ready
  resource_group: traffic_light
  script:
    - # TODO: You need to implement it using the GitLab API.
    - # The end condition for `traffic_light` is
    - # the end of job1-3 execution.
    - # In other words, this job must be checked and waited
    - # through gitlab api until job 1,2,3 is finished.
    - # Since this job locks the execution of a `traffic_light` job
    - # in another pipeline, the `starting_signal` job in another 
    - # pipeline does not succeed.
```

(I didn't test it myself, so this method needs a review.)

Referenecs:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understood correct in `traffic_light` job I should wait for execution finish of job1-3 in concurrent pipeline. What I don't like in this approach - your ci minutes will be wasted on checking status of concurrent pipeline.

Comment: If you are concerned about ci minutes, you can use self-hosted gitlab-runner for `traffic_light` using `tags` keyword.

Many cloud vendor today provide free tier instances, which are sufficient to run simple wait jobs like `traffic_light`.

Comment: Looks like gitlab counts minutes even at self-hosted runners. I am trying to retry job wich have tag for self-hosted runner - but it don't launches and shows message about pipeline minutes limit exceed: https://i.imgur.com/vBftxmk.png

Comment: If it is related to the this(https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/58942) issue, it seems that the specific runner does not work once the quota is exceeded. I'm not sure if this is clear, but this is not directly related to your original question, so I would suggest posting a separate question here or on gitlab.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a dedicated runner for the jobs1-3.

1. [Setup a new runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/) with an unique tag eg 'jobs-1-2-3' and [set the option `concurrent` to `1`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html).
2. Add the unique tag eg 'jobs-1-2-3' to the jobs in question.

   ```
   job1:
     tags:
       - jobs-1-2-3
   job2:
     tags:
       - jobs-1-2-3
   job3:
     tags:
       - jobs-1-2-3
   ```

IMHO this is less effort and more reliable.

Comment: Not sure it will work. Possible scenario: pipeline1(p1) run job1(j1), then pipeline2(p2) run job1(j1), then pipeline 1 start job2. I need p1 run j1, j2, j3 then p2 run j1, j2, j3.

Looks like resource group will do same

Comment: Since the new runner will process only one job at a time and due to the unique tag no other runner will pick the jobs, is ensured p2 waits for p1 to finish. Also see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-pending-pipelines

Comment: I don't want to cancel pending pipelines. As I said there are other jobs - they should work concurrently. So are you saing if two pipelines are running and concurrent option is set - runner will always pick jobs from first pipeline?

Comment: Yes, the runner will finish the jobs in p1 before processing jobs from p2.

Comment: This answer don't works with latest gitlab anymore. Jobs execution order are mixed between pipelines.